# What is the best way to go about archiving an AWS Dyanamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an Amazon DynamoDB used for a project that will be on hold for at least 6 months. I want to archive the database to remove as much of the day-to-day costs as is reasonably possible. I'm hoping I can somehow export the data to some backup format and store it in Amazon S3 storage. I would then want to be able to restore the data to resurrect the DynamoDB at some future date.

Comment: Use the AWS SDK to write application logic that can read the data in an Amazon DynamoDB table, store the data in JSON, then place the data in an Amazon S3 bucket (you many want to look at Glacier too). This can all be performed using AWS SDK and custom logic.

Comment: Why would you do that when there are several non-code options available and are more cost efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, but first of all it's important to understand DynamoDB free tier:

1. You get 25GB of storage free per region
2. You get 25RCU/WCU free per region

So if it's a single table and less than 25GB you can keep that table in DynamoDB for free.

Backup options:

[AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorksAWS.html) : Takes a snapshot of your table and handles the storage medium. You can also choose to keep in cold storage for a lower cost. No S3 costs for putting or getting the data later.

[Export to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html) : This built in feature to DynamoDB allows you to export the table to S3 in DynamoDB JSON or ION format. You will incur export costs as well as puts to S3. Later you can use the import from S3 feature to restore the table.

Comment: I am well over the free tiers thanks. I now have the tables being backed up using the AWS Backup option you suggested and set to be transferred to cold storage as soon as possible. Thanks.